# How to compare a value in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, compare

I am getting data from some ajax operation, and trying to use javascript to do some conditional checks actually

so when i print the response from the ajax  like

```
document.write(response)
```

**result**

```
[object Object]
```

when i print something like `document.write(JSON.stringify(response))`

**result**

```
{"status":"failed","login":["This field is required."],"password":["This field is required."]}
```

so above is the actual data i am getting what i am trying to do is

```
if(response.status === 'failed')
            window.location.href = response.next;
        else if ('login' in response && response['login']==["This field is required."])
           {
              $("#message").html(<p>Username is required</p>); 
           }
        else if ('password' in response && response['password']==["This field is required."])
           {
              $("#message").html(<p>Password is required</p>); 
           }
```

But the `&&` condition `response['login']==["This field is required."]` is not working 
so how to check the value of above type in javascript ?

Note: ****New to javascript ****

Comment: if you're going to have an array of values for login, you might want to use the [indexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) method instead of "==". `reponse.login.indexOf('This field is required') !== -1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the different properties of the response object using the dot operator.

```
response.login[0] === "This field is required."
```

Just to let you know what's going on here - you're getting back a json object. Properties in a json object can be access by simple using .PropertyName. Your login property is an array, and  ou you want to access the first item in the array, so you use the [0] indexer. Lastly, you're comparing strings, so best practice in javascript is to use the === operator, which will compare type and value.

Comment: The problem is not because they are not using the dot operator - the bracketed operator is just as syntactically correct.  Nor is it the lack of ===.  But rather the fact that they is comparing arrays, when really they want to be comparing strings.

Answer (score 1):

Try this validation instead. It compares first position of `login` array.

```
response['login'][0] == "This field is required."
```

Answer (score 1):

Because an array is not equal to another array. Check `response['login'][0]` to compare the strings instead.

```
> var array1 = ['array'];

> array1 == ['array']
< false

> array1[0] == 'array'
< true
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `[]` . this is array. you must compare with string

Comment: -1: It is not clear what `[]` you are suggesting to remove. And unless you remove it in both the response AND the if statement, then you will need to do something extra still to get this working

Answer (score 0):

`JSON` is basically a transportable format of Javascript syntax. You're comparing the wrong things. Once a JSON string is decode in Javascript, it becomes a **NATIVE** javascript object/array. As such, given your sample JSOns tring, you should be doing

```
(response.password[0] == 'This field is required')
```

Note the lack of `[]` brackets around the "this field..." text. Your code is effectively

```
if (string == array)
```

when it should be

```
if (string == string)
```

(using the same positions for the comparison members).

Answer (score 0):

you may try this:-

```
response['login'][0] == "This field is required."
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare arrays in JavaScript with `==`.

It's like this: `{} == {} // false` two objects are not the same.

So you would also expect: `new Foo() == new Foo(); // false`

and similarly: `new Array() == new Array() // false`

`[]` is shorthand for `new Array()` (it's a little more complex, but ignore that for now).