# How to push an object into array and then call parts of object in that array

Tags: javascript, arrays, blackjack

I'm making a blackjack game in Javascript which requires making objects for each card so that multiple cards equal 10. I'm then calling a random number and pushing the corresponding card into the array dealerArr, my problem is when I want to add the values of those objects in the array together, It doesn't seem to be possible, here's the code.

```js
var dealerArr = [];
var playerArr = [];
var dealerTotal = 0;
var playerTotal = 0;
var two = {
  value: 2
}
var three = {
  value: 3
}
var four = {
  value: 4
}
var five = {
  value: 5
}
var six = {
  value: 6
}
var seven = {
  value: 7
}
var eight = {
  value: 8
}
var nine = {
  value: 9
}
var ten = {
  value: 10
}
var jack = {
  value: 10
}
var queen = {
  value: 10
}
var king = {
  value: 10
}
var ace = {
  value: 11
}


function calcTotal(arr) {
  var sum = 0;
  for (var object of arr) {
    sum += object.value;
  }
  return sum;
}

while (calcTotal(dealerArr) < 17) {
  var randomCard = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 13) + 1)
  if (randomCard = 1) {
    dealerArr.push(two);
  } else if (randomCard = 2) {
    dealerArr.push(three);
  } else if (randomCard = 3) {
    dealerArr.push(four);
  } else if (randomCard = 4) {
    dealerArr.push(five);
  } else if (randomCard = 5) {
    dealerArr.push(six);
  } else if (randomCard = 6) {
    dealerArr.push(seven);
  } else if (randomCard = 7) {
    dealerArr.push(eight);
  } else if (randomCard = 8) {
    dealerArr.push(nine);
  } else if (randomCard = 9) {
    dealerArr.push(ten);
  } else if (randomCard = 10) {
    dealerArr.push(jack);
  } else if (randomCard = 11) {
    dealerArr.push(queen);
  } else if (randomCard = 12) {
    dealerArr.push(king);
  } else if (randomCard = 13) {
    dealerArr.push(ace);
  }
  console.log(dealerTotal)
}
```

Comment: `randomCard ===` ... a single `=` doesn't compare but assigns a value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare a value in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18831104/how-to-compare-a-value-in-javascript)

Comment: Just to talk about the game, do keep in mind that the Ace acts as a 1 and 11.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I was just starting simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [problem](https://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2008/01/using_the_assig.html) is that you used `=` instead of `==` in `if` statements.

Single equals in JS (and many more languages) does an [assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Assignment_operators), while double and triple equals do the [comparision](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Assignment_operators).

So use this format instead:

```js
var dealerArr = [];
var playerArr = [];
var dealerTotal = 0;
var playerTotal = 0;
var two = {
  value: 2
}
var three = {
  value: 3
}
var four = {
  value: 4
}
var five = {
  value: 5
}
var six = {
  value: 6
}
var seven = {
  value: 7
}
var eight = {
  value: 8
}
var nine = {
  value: 9
}
var ten = {
  value: 10
}
var jack = {
  value: 10
}
var queen = {
  value: 10
}
var king = {
  value: 10
}
var ace = {
  value: 11
}


function calcTotal(arr) {
  var sum = 0;
  for (var object of arr) {
    sum += object.value;
  }
  return sum;
}

while (calcTotal(dealerArr) < 17) {
  var randomCard = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 13) + 1)
  if (randomCard == 1) {
    dealerArr.push(two);
  } else if (randomCard == 2) {
    dealerArr.push(three);
  } else if (randomCard == 3) {
    dealerArr.push(four);
  } else if (randomCard == 4) {
    dealerArr.push(five);
  } else if (randomCard == 5) {
    dealerArr.push(six);
  } else if (randomCard == 6) {
    dealerArr.push(seven);
  } else if (randomCard == 7) {
    dealerArr.push(eight);
  } else if (randomCard == 8) {
    dealerArr.push(nine);
  } else if (randomCard == 9) {
    dealerArr.push(ten);
  } else if (randomCard == 10) {
    dealerArr.push(jack);
  } else if (randomCard == 11) {
    dealerArr.push(queen);
  } else if (randomCard == 12) {
    dealerArr.push(king);
  } else if (randomCard == 13) {
    dealerArr.push(ace);
  }
  console.log(dealerTotal)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Jonas is correct, in JS a single = is an assignment, whereas == is a comparison and === is a strict comparison (value and type comparison)